# Append new columns into Excel with MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, append, multiple-columns

I would like to ask how to use MATLAB to append new columns into existing excel file without altering the original data in the file? In my case I don't know the original number of columns and rows in the file and it is inefficient to open the files one by one and check in practice. Another difficulty is that the new columns may have different number of rows to the existing data so that I cannot use the trick of reading in the data, forming a new matrix and replace the data with the new matrix.

I have seen many posts teaching people how to add new rows but adding new column seems quite a different thing since the columns are named by letters instead of numbers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reading in the data, use size on the array to determine the number of columns, and then use xlswrite with the range that you want. Have a look here for a function to turn the column number into the excel format: http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54153-dynamic-ranges-using-xlswrite

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it with the following code:

```
%%%

if (step==1)
     xlswrite(filename,array,sheetname,'A1'); %Create the file 
else
    [~,~,Data]=xlsread(filename,sheetname);  %read in all the old data 

    OriCol=size(Data,2);           %get the column number of the old data

    NewCol=OriCol+1;    %the new array is placed right next to the original data

    ColLetter=xlcolumnletter(NewCol);  

    StartCell=[ColLetter,'1']; 

    xlswrite(filename,array,sheetname,StartCell); 
end
```